# Stripe iOS - STPAddCardViewController with Card.io?

Tags: ios, objective-c, stripe-payments, card.io

I am trying to add the 'Scan Card' capability to my STPAddCardViewController.

According to a few Google searches, all I was required to do was install the Card.io library alongside Stripe, however when I go ahead and present the STPAddCardViewController, I am not seeing the ability to scan a card:

```
STPAddCardViewController *addCardViewController = [[STPAddCardViewController alloc] init];
addCardViewController.delegate = self;

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addCardViewController];
[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Are the some specific customizations I'm missing to get Card.io integrated?

Comment: Have you checked weather your publishable key properly configured, before initiating `STPAddCardViewController ` instance, In my case I did not initiated publishable key.

Comment: @adam: were you able to get this working? I am facing a similar where i could see the Scan card button in stripe Add card screen but the camera is not scanning and filling the card.